# MongoDB: get only the first sub-document inside an array which is present as attribute of a document

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection of this kind of document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6047b855a6ce7d24a4cda693"
    },
    "address": "Bergamo, Via S. Bernardino, 57",
    "products": [{
        "productId": "6047b855a6ce7d24a4cda694",
        "qty": 7,
        "alarmTh": 5
    }, {
        "productId": "6047b855a6ce7d24a4cda695",
        "qty": 5,
        "alarmTh": 5
    }],
    "_class": "warehouseservice.team2.warehouseservice.models.Warehouse"
```

}

I need to find a product with a specific productId. Let's say that I want the object with Id = 6047b855a6ce7d24a4cda694, the result that I want is the following:

```
{
    "productId": "6047b855a6ce7d24a4cda694",
    "qty": 7,
    "alarmTh": 5
}
```

I tried with this:

```
db.warehouse.find({"products.productId": "6047b855a6ce7d24a4cda694"}, {"products.$": 1, _id: 0})
```

but this returns:

```
{ products: [ { productId: '6047b855a6ce7d24a4cda694', qty: 7, alarmTh: 5 } ] }
```

so an array, but I want only one single object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation pipeline and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "products.productId": "6047b855a6ce7d24a4cda694"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      products: {
        "$first": "$products"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$products"
    }
  }
]);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "alarmTh": 5,
    "productId": "6047b855a6ce7d24a4cda694",
    "qty": 7
  }
]
```

Comment: this return an empty array. Moreover I would like to have only the object, without array ( [] )

Comment: sorry the output is correct but I would like to have only one object without the array if it is possible as if it were a single document

Comment: sorry again, this not work because this query returns the first sub-object. If I want the second object this query does not work

Comment: Hi, you question suggest that you want **only** the first sub-document. Could you please update your question?

Comment: thank you Haniel. I have just updated the question. Yes I want only the first sub-document that match the attribuite passed as input

Comment: What mongo driver are you using?

Comment: The driver that I'm using is Java 4.2 with mongoDB 4.4.4

Comment: Having looked in the doc, the result will always be a list of documents, even if there is only one document.